# Improve Case When performance?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

See SQL query below:

```
   SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status=0 AND type  IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_0',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=0 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_0',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=2 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_2',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=2 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_2',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_3',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_3',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=4 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_4',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=4 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_4',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=5 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_5',
           SUM(CASE WHEN status=5 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_5'
    FROM sales;
```

It take half a seconds to get the result, I would like to improve the performance further. Any suggestion What it can be done?

`sales` table are `innodb` and `status` `type` are indexed. Over 50,000 rows in `sales` table.

my.ini file:

```
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.36
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.1.36/data



#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 500M
```

3GB Ram, Intel Dual-Core CPU.

Comment: You are `SUM`ming 1? Why not use some kind of `COUNT` solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add a `WHERE` clause on the query

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN status=0 AND type  IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_0',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=0 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_0',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=2 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_2',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=2 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_2',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_3',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=3 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_3',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=4 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_4',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=4 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_4',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=5 AND type IN (0, 5, 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'a_5',
        SUM(CASE WHEN status=5 AND type IN (1, 6, 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'b_5'
FROM    sales
WHERE   status IN (0,2,3,4,5) AND
        type IN (0,1,5,6,7,8)
```

Comment: Eh? You mean I should have multiple SQL queries?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back no, leave your query as is but *add the `where` clause* on it. The difference is that, without `where` clause, the server will calculate all the records within the table but with `WHERE` clause, only the records that matches the condition will be calculated.

Comment: Oh fantastic :) That work really very fast. I should have thought of that!!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the values with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales AS 'a0' WHERE status=0 AND type  IN (0, 5, 7)
```

and similar for the other 7 queries. You can combine all queries into one large query with a join.

Comment: How can you can combine all that into into one large query with a join?